# Can a user with dynamic IP address be blocked?

Tags: web-services

Now I am trying to build something and my client wants to block certain IP addresses which make to many requests to the web service. Now what I would like to know is that if I block a user with a dynamic IP address, can't he just reset his modem and start over?

Comment: If you're blocking purely on IP, yes. Usually, it's a better idea to throttle everyone (putting requests in a queue) rather then block them outright, and whitelist exceptions (often used wireless access points, big offices with one external IP, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, if the IP is dynamic, although a router reset might not immediately change it, the IP will change at some point and then they're unblocked.
Also, if a legitimate user then gets assigned that blocked IP, then you've unintentionally blocked an innocent user.

An alternative way of doing this might be to require some sort of unique key to make the requests then you could ignore requests made with keys you have blocked.