# IP blocking on hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, ipv4

I am trying to block my website's access by a particular router, but that router has a dynamic IP. It changes the IP dynamically, so even after blocking one IP of the router it can still access the website after it has changed its IP. How do I block that specific router from accessing my website?

Comment: you can not do that. You have to keep blocking IPs.

Comment: Leaving PHP and Apache apart by now... How do you recognise the router? What features does it have that makes you nod and think "yeah, here it is again"?

Comment: How can you block that which you don't know?

Comment: set a value in localstorage on target browser. if value is present in localstorage set browser to use to mine bitcoins for you on full throttle via several webworkers keeping the ui thread responsive. Have default css hide all content, then use javascript to show all content. without javascript no site, with javascript slow computer... or go boring, set a cookie, redirect on cookie. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978726/how-to-do-htaccess-redirect-based-on-cookie-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a user with dynamic IP address be blocked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405375/can-a-user-with-dynamic-ip-address-be-blocked)

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint for an alternative to IPs.

Answer (score 1):

You could block an IP range (if you see within which range the router gets its IP addresses)

> 120.120.0.0 - 120.120.255.255

Comment: This a nice way to accomplish ISP-wide blocking, e.g. keep Vodaphone users away.

Comment: the range varies, its going from 110.***.***.*** to 227.***.***.***